# Using virtual objects with shared_ptr/unique_ptr in a container class

Tags: c++, c++14, virtual, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I am fairly new to C++ (coming from Java/PHP). Basically, I need to create a container class that will hold a reference of a unique/shared pointer to a virtual class instance (Base class). I am unable to get this piece of code to compile (I am using MSVC 2015).

The compiler error is:

```
error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Here is a sample application to reproduce the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base {
    public:
        virtual void foo() const = 0;
        virtual void bar() const = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        void foo() const override {
            std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;

        };

        void bar() const override{
            std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
        };
};

class ContainerUnique {
    public:
        ContainerUnique() {
            ptr = nullptr;
        }

        void assignPtr(const Base &instance) {
            auto ptr = std::make_unique<Base>(instance);
            ptr.swap(ptr);
        };

        std::unique_ptr<Base> getPtr() {
            return ptr;
        };

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr;
};

class ContainerShared {
    public:
        ContainerShared() {
            ptr = nullptr;
        }

        void assignPtr(const Base &instance) {
            auto ptr = std::make_shared<Base>(instance);
            ptr.swap(ptr);
        };

        std::shared_ptr<Base> getPtr() {
            return ptr;
        };

    private:
        std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr;
};

int main() {
    Derived derived1 = Derived();
    Derived derived2 = Derived();

    ContainerUnique cu = ContainerUnique();
    ContainerShared cs = ContainerShared();

    cu.assignPtr(derived1);
    cs.assignPtr(derived2);

    std::unique_ptr<Base> uptr = cu.getPtr();
    std::shared_ptr<Base> sptr = cs.getPtr();

    return 0;
}
```

Please advice

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Base> getPtr()` returns a copy. You can't copy `unique_ptr`. I'm not sure what semantics you are trying to achieve. Is `getPtr` expected to share ownership? If so, you can't use a `unique_ptr`. If not, don't return a smart pointer.

Comment: Unrelated to the error: you don't need the overriden default constructors and you shouldn't be using `ptr.swap` (or a temporary variable of the same name) in this case. Just `ptr = std::make_unique<Base>(instance);` is sufficient

Comment: @UnholySheep. I just tried it, compiler throws `error C2259: 'Base': cannot instantiate abstract class`

Comment: `assignPtr()` receives a `const Base&` reference and tries to copy-construct a new `Base` object, not a `Derived`, thus the error. Also, `assignPtr()` is assigning the new `std::unique_ptr` to a local variable `ptr` and then `swap`ing it with itself, not the class's `ptr` member.  You need to change `ContainerUnique::assignPtr()` to take a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` as input and `std::move()` it into the class's `ptr` member, and change `ContainerShared::assignPtr()` to take a `std::shared_ptr<Base>` as input and assign it to the class's `ptr` member.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: But you'd be trying (and failing) to take ownership with `unique_ptr` of a variable with automatic lifetime.  This whole design is an X-Y problem, so much breakage, so many different directions to go to make it legal, and nothing describing the intended use so no way to choose between them.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, since `assignPtr()` wants to take ownership, the caller must use `unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr` to manage dynamically allocated objects, not use objects on the stack.  Otherwise, another solution that is more inline with what the OP attempted is to pass a template parameter to `assignPtr` so it knows which derived class to instantiate when making a copy of the input.  Then it can take ownership of the copy

Answer (score 0):

You should think about object ownership, and where objects live (stack or heap), neither of which you may have had to focus on in Java.

Because `ContainerUnique` has a `unique_ptr` member, I infer that it is intended to own the pointed-to object. It is being given the obligation to delete it. This is inconsistent with the rest, because `derived1` is on the stack, so has no need to be owned by anything, and cannot be deleted. Instead, suppose we created `derived1` on the heap:

```
auto derived1 = std::make_unique<Derived>();
```

That creates it on the heap, so that it needs managing, and identifies us as owning the object by storing its pointer in a `unique_ptr`. To transfer ownership with a `unique_ptr`, we have to tweak the interface:

```
// Interface
void ContainerUnique::assignPtr(std::unique_ptr<Base> instance);
// Call site
cu.assignPtr(std::move(derived1));
```

If we take a raw reference or pointer, there is nothing in the interface or the call site to reflect the intended change in ownership. If we take a reference-to-Base, and call `std::make_unique` we are making a copy, and making a copy of a Base (losing any Derived data). Taking a `unique_ptr` is probably the clearest way to communicate ownership transfer.

Putting it together:

```
#include <memory>

struct Base {
    virtual void foo() const = 0;
    virtual void bar() const = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base {
    void foo() const override { }
    void bar() const override { }
};

class ContainerUnique {
    public:
        void assignPtr(std::unique_ptr<Base> instance) {
            ptr.swap(instance);
        };

        std::unique_ptr<Base> getPtr() {
            return std::move(ptr);
        };

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr;
};

int main() {
    auto derived1 = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    auto cu = ContainerUnique();
    cu.assignPtr(std::move(derived1));
    auto uptr = cu.getPtr();
}
```